# Home Launcher in CM12 lags due to Tasker's accessibility feature

Tags: cyanogenmod, tasker, oneplus-one

I'm using the [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) app and noticed that if its accessibility service is turned on the Home Launcher seems to lag horribly. The lag is not only irritating but it also breaks the smooth animation of Lollipop. My views are shared by a user in this bug [here](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/BACON-3298). Unfortunately, the bug is still unresolved.

What can I do to fix this lag other than to turn off accessibility feature of [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)?

Note that this accessibility feature is important because the technique in my previous question ([Tasker app is skipping a task when profile is activated](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106432/tasker-app-is-skipping-a-task-when-profile-is-activated)) is unresolved for some reason. Also, my other devices with Android 4.2.1 and 4.4.2 (both stock ROM) doesn't need accessibility service turned on to achieve my goal using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en).

---

Device: OnePlus One

OS version: CM12 (bacon)

Tasker version : 4.6u3

Comment: I now tested this on cm-12.1-20151117-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1K6 and the issue doesn't persist.